# Netty - How worker threads work

Tags: event-handling, websocket, nio, netty, worker

I want to understand how netty worker threads work . as per the code , for each new request we get nextwoker() any one of the worker thread and allocate it for processing of events of client .  SO a single thread will be able to handle different request from different clients as per my understanding .

I have one question here whether for client(channel/socket) all the events coming in that particular channel are handled by the same thread or can different threads can handle them .
My assumption is single thread handles all events (excluding Future events) . 
But as per the documentation of MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor they tell that for a channel - different threads handle different events .

To verify this i wrote a small program using a single client and worker threadppol which has 50 worker threads but when i keep sleep in message received event , my client waits for next message received call . which confirms that single thread per client is allocated .
Please clarify ...

Comment: May be you need to look into this thread here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796717/jboss-netty-how-to-serve-2-connections-using-3-worker-threads

Comment: I understand that netty with thread pool handles 10000 conenctions , my question here is different . I saw the source code and saw that they do a round robin to allocate a thread for each client request . so  100 worker threads and 10000 connections means . one thread takes care of 100 connections using java NIO  . I understand that part well . Will all the events in a single connection will be handled my the same thread or diffenrent threads that is my question .

Answer (score 2):

The same Worker thread will be used for the Channel all the time. So its safe to asume thats the case.

If you use a OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor this may not be the case anymore.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, Netty uses worker threads to handle incoming connections.

You should not block (sleep in) these worker threads otherwise your clients will be waiting for a response and you will also waste a thread that could have been used for process another request.

What you should do is to dispatch your work to another thread pool using OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutore; or you can do it using your own Executor in `messageReceived()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's only safe to assume that the same thread will *not* be used for the same client.